# Stumped on ASCII art challenge

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, ascii-art

all,

I'm working on some of the challenges at CodinGame.com and I'm having some trouble with a challenge that requires me to display a letter in ASCII form using a loop of rows with "#"s and spaces where each "letter" is 3 characters long and 5 tall. For example:

```
Line 1 = " # "<br>
Line 2 = "# #"<br>
Line 3 = "###"<br>
Line 4 = "# #"<br>
Line 5 = "# #"<br>
```

Here is the relevant code for the program up to now:

```
int L; // Length of ASCII art char, always 3
scanf("%d", &L); // <- CodinGame scanf's all values from case into stdin 
int H; // Height of ASCII art char, always 5
scanf("%d", &H); fgetc(stdin);
char T[257]; // <- Characters that must be turned into ASCII art
char lclcpy[1025]; // <- Copy array for me to use outside of loop.

fgets(T, 257, stdin); // <- T is drawn from case to stdin

for (int i = 0; i <= H; i++) {
    char ROW[1025]; // <- String containing the current row of "#"s and spaces 
    strncpy(lclcpy, ROW, sizeof(lclcpy)); // <- I copy the row into my local copy.
    fgets(ROW, 1025, stdin); // <- Program draws ROW into its stdin.
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", lclcpy); // <- I print out the value of ROW on this line alone to debug. CodinGame uses stderr for debugging purposes.
}
```

Once the loop is complete, I end up with the alphabet in ASCII art, which is what my lclcpy looped through and printed.

What I want to do is copy only the segments of the big ASCII art image that correspond to a specific letter. I was able to do this in C++ because strings make life worth living, but I'm tearing my hair out trying to do this in C.

I figure I'd create an array of character pointers, with each element of the array pointing to the segments of ROW/lclcpy that contain a letter's data. Unfortunately, I've had no luck trying to do anything with character pointer arrays or two-dimensional character arrays. I keep getting segfaults and other memory problems. I'm not comfortably familiar with pointers yet. Seems I can only think in string mode, and nothing I've found has helped. Any help is greatly appreciated. Please consider my lack of experience. Thank you.

Comment: When you call `strncpy` the array `ROW` is not initialized, giving you *undefined behavior*.

Comment: https://www.codingame.com/games/puzzles/ is the specific website, ASCII Art is the exercise.

Comment: check that your char array is null terminated, otherwise fgets will fail